# TimestampType Difference and reset hour in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have following two columns in

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{TimestampType, ArrayType}

statusWithOutDuplication.withColumn("requestTime", unix_timestamp( col("requestTime"), "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS").cast("Timestamp"))
statusWithOutDuplication.withColumn("responseTime", unix_timestamp( col("responseTime"), "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS").cast("Timestamp"))
```

I want to pass requestTime & responseTime into the following UDF and find the difference after 
setting Minute and Seconds into "0"

```
val split_hour_range_udf = udf { (startDateTime: TimestampType ,
                                      endDateTime: TimestampType ) =>

      }
```

In Python we have "replace" (`startDateTime.replace(second=0,minute=0)`) what is the equivalent in Scala?.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `UDF` as below, send the value as an string and convert as `Timestamp` later. in `UDF`

```
val timeDFiff = udf((start: String , end : String) => {
  //convert to timestamp and find the difference
})
```

and use it as

```
df.withColumn("responseTime", timeDiff($"requestTime", $"responseTime"))
```

Rather than using an UDF you can use built in Spark function like [dateDiff](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#datediff(org.apache.spark.sql.Column,%20org.apache.spark.sql.Column))

Comment: I want to apply some more logic and create list out of it., so UDF is needed for me. After converting it to TimestampType how to find difference in UDF also I want to reset Minute and Second to "0"

Comment: what do you want to find in the udf? do you want to find the number of  hours/days/week/months?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{TimestampType, ArrayType}

statusWithOutDuplication.withColumn("requestTime", unix_timestamp( col("requestTime"), "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"))
statusWithOutDuplication.withColumn("responseTime", unix_timestamp( col("responseTime"), "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"))

//This resets minute and second to 0
def resetMinSec(colName: String) = {
    col(colName) - minute(col(colName).cast("TimeStamp"))*60 - second(col(colname).cast("Timestamp"))
}

//create a new column with the difference between unixtimes
statusWithOutDuplication.select((resetMinSec("responseTime") - resetMinSec("requestTime")).as("diff"))
```

Note that i didn't cast `requestTime`/`responseTime` to "Timestamp", you should cast after finding the difference.

The udf approach should be similar but using some scala methods to obtain minutes/seconds from a Timestamp.

Hope this helps a little!